# max number of decimals allowed by CSS transform scale?

Tags: css

I'm trying to reduce the number of decimals of a JS operation and use the result to set a `transform: scale(x)` inline CSS to an element.

I can't find any reference to know how many decimals are allowed by such CSS function.

I want to know how many numbers are allowed (and used by the browser in the transformation) after the comma. (0.0000000N)

Comment: Not clear...you want to know the max number or minimum required?

Comment: the max number of decimals allowed (0.00000000?), how many numbers are allowed (and taken in account in the CSS transformation) after the comma?

Comment: ...and what would be the point in that many decimals...I'm struggling to find a use case?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it was just a way to ask about the information specifying that I want an answer with some official reference. By the way I've changed it.

Comment: There's no unique answer to this question as browsers are implemented in so many ways... Anyway, here you have a good starting point: http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/

Comment: @Paulie_D I just want to know it, the reason is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Vi100 good refference!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#funcdef-scale) defines the value for scale as a `<number>`, which [is defined](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#number-value) as:

> A number is either an `<integer>` or zero or more decimal digits followed by a dot (.) followed by one or more decimal digits and optionally an exponent composed of "e" or "E" and an integer. It corresponds to the `<number-token>` production in the CSS Syntax Module [CSS3SYN]. As with integers, the first character of a number may be immediately preceded by - or + to indicate the number’s sign.

Note the lack of how many "more" decimal digits are allowed. So any limit will be imposed by the browser, which will obviously vary by browser.

Comment: Thank you, it helps!
Are you aware of the limitations imposed by the major browsers maybe?

Comment: @Vi100's comment has a link to a good start. I think you'd need to do some searching. I don't have any off the top of my head though.

Comment: I'm not sure the "limit" is imposed...more about how the browser *interprets* fractional values and renders sub-pixels. Good answer though.

Answer (score 4):

As it seems it could be useful for others and amending the accepted question by extending it I'll upgrade my comment to an answer:

In the last term, the number of decimals you'll get depends mainly on the browser implementation so, depending on your targets you'll need to do some more research. Here you have an excellent post and a good starting point:

[Browser Rounding and Fractional Pixels](http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/)

Comment: Thanks for posting it as an answer :)